# how to display rating value that is stored in database as number of stars in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ratingbar

i add rating data to firebase database without problem 
here it is

[image]

Now i want get it and display rating in my rating bar 
Here is my code
Rating database reference `ratingReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rating")`
Getting data from database

```
private fun getFoodRating(foodID: String) {
var query: Query=ratingReference.orderByChild("foodId").equalTo(foodID)
query.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
    var count =0
    var sum=0.00
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

for (r in p0.children){
    var item: Rating? =r.getValue(Rating::class.java)
    sum+= item?.ratingValue?.toDouble()!!
    count++
}
                if (count != 0){
                    var average=sum/count
                    ratingBar.rating=average.toFloat()
                }

            }
        })

    }
```

But there is no displaying rating on rating bar 
How fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure that condition `count != 0` is `true`? Try to set breakpoint

Comment: @Boken how to make it ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

Comment: yes , it seems like it is null , but why is it null ? I declared in for loop that in each iterration count increments so it must be 1 at least